# Initializing a pointer variable of the type structure

Tags: c

Consider a pointer variable as defined below

```
struct socket_info
{
    int hsocket;
    int * buffer;
}

typedef struct socket_info * t_socket_info;
```

Now we I want to declare the pointer variable and use it as follow

```
t_socket_info t_socket;
```

How to allocate the memory for `t_socket` pointer variable

Comment: the code is struct socket_info{ int hsocket; int *buffer;}                typedef struct socket_info * t_socket_info;                                                       t_socket_info t_socket;

Comment: Is it C or C++? Add the language tag.

Comment: Be sure that you want to allocate it dynamically (during runtime). This is typically inevitable when you have an array of such structures, the number of which is unknown during compilation (e.g., if you want to determine this number based on user input). Otherwise, you may as well allocate it statically.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after the struct definition. (and: you don't need the typedef)

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would do

```
t_socket = malloc(sizeof(struct socket_info));
```

or

```
t_socket = malloc(sizeof *t_socket);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t_socket=(socket_info *)malloc(sizeof(socket_info))
```